# Autohotkey remapping keys (Browser Home) on bluetooth keyboard not working

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I am using inca bluetooth keyboard. At this keyboard Fn keys are reverted and there is no fn lock. I am trying to use autohotkey script in order to remapping the Browser Home key to ESC key. the script is:

```
Browser_Home::Esc
```

but it doesn't work. I also used the SC and VK versions of this fuction like below.

```
SC132::Esc
```

```
VKAC::Esc
```

Any version of this mapping fuction is not working. However it is possible to remap other keys on this keyboard. What is the solution of this problem? How can i use the Esc key instead of Browser Home key?

Comment: How did you try to determine the SC/VK? [Here's](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) a quick tutorial just in case you would've done it incorrectly.

Comment: I determined the SC/VK values according to the tutorial. There is no mistake.

Comment: I am using Omoton keyboard with the same layout. SC132::Esc works for me. AHK version 1.1.33.11.